# Implementing clearTable, grow and shrink on a hash table

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, hash-map

I've gone through previous questions about implementing hash tables in python, but I have something little more specific. I am handling collisions with linear probing, and I want to grow/shrink my table when I go below/above a given loading factor. My put/get methods are heavily based from [this source](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/Hashing.html).

I would like to get some feedback on my grow/shrink methods. I'd also like to know if my method for clearing the table (clearTable) is approached correctly. My main question stems from the fact that `del newHashTable` might not be deleting the contents of the hash table, just like the references, so could that cause a memory problem? (Excuse my lack of vocabulary.)

Please find my implementation below:

```
import copy

class HashTable:
    def __init__(self, size = 11):
        self.MAXLOADFACTOR = 0.75
        self.MINLOADFACTOR = 0.25
        self.MINSIZE = size
        self.size = size
        self.totalItems = 0
        self.slots = [None] * self.size
        self.data = [None] * self.size

    def put(self, key, data):
        hashvalue = self.hashfunction(key)

        if self.slots[hashvalue] == None: # new data
            self.slots[hashvalue] = key
            self.data[hashvalue] = data
            self.totalItems += 1
            self.checkGrow()
        else:
            if self.slots[hashvalue] == key:
                self.data[hashvalue] = data # replace
            else: #collision has occured
                nextslot = self.rehash(hashvalue, len(self.slots))
                while self.slots[nextslot] != None and self.slots[nextslot] != key:
                    nextslot = self.rehash(nextslot,len(self.slots))
                if self.slots[nextslot] == None: #new data
                    self.slots[nextslot] = key
                    self.data[nextslot] = data
                    self.totalItems += 1
                    self.checkGrow()
                else:
                    self.data[nextslot] = data # replace

    # assume key will always be int or str, for illustration
    def hashfunction(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return key % self.size
        else:
            s = str(key)
            return sum([ord(c) for c in s]) % self.size

    def rehash(self, oldhash, size):
        return (oldhash + 1) % size

    def get(self, key):
        startslot = self.hashfunction(key)
        data = None
        stop = False
        found = False
        position = startslot
        while self.slots[position] != None and not found and not stop:
            if self.slots[position] == key:
                found = True
                data = self.data[position] # key was where we expected
            else:
                position = self.rehash(position, len(self.slots)) # check next
                if position == startslot: # we checked all spots
                    stop = True
        return data

    def remove(self, key):
        hashvalue = self.hashfunction(key)

        if self.slots[hashvalue] == None: # key does not exist
            return False
        else:
            if self.slots[hashvalue] == key:
                self.slots[hashvalue] = None # clear
                self.data[hashvalue] = None
                self.totalItems -= 1
                self.checkShrink()
            else: #collision has occured
                nextslot = self.rehash(hashvalue, len(self.slots))
                while self.slots[nextslot] != None and self.slots[nextslot] != key:
                    nextslot = self.rehash(nextslot,len(self.slots))
                if self.slots[nextslot] == None: # key does not exist
                    return False
                else:
                    self.slots[nextslot] = None # clear
                    self.data[nextslot] = None
                    self.totalItems -= 1
                    self.checkShrink()

    def checkGrow(self):
        if self.totalItems > self.MAXLOADFACTOR * self.size:
                self.grow()

    def grow(self):
        newSize = 2 * self.size
        newHashTable = HashTable(newSize)
        for key in self.slots:
            if key != None:
                newHashTable.put(key, self.get(key))
        self.size = newSize
        self.slots = copy.deepcopy(newHashTable.slots)
        self.data = copy.deepcopy(newHashTable.data)
        del newHashTable

    def checkShrink(self):
        if self.totalItems < self.MINLOADFACTOR * self.size and self.size >= self.MINSIZE * 2:
            self.shrink()

    def shrink(self):
        newSize = self.size // 2
        newHashTable = HashTable(newSize)
        for key in self.slots:
            if key != None:
                newHashTable.put(key, self.get(key))
        self.size = newSize
        self.slots = copy.deepcopy(newHashTable.slots)
        self.data = copy.deepcopy(newHashTable.data)
        del newHashTable

    def clearTable(self, size = 11):
        self.MAXLOADFACTOR = 0.75
        self.MINLOADFACTOR = 0.25
        self.MINSIZE = size
        self.size = size
        self.totalItems = 0
        self.slots = [None] * self.size
        self.data = [None] * self.size

    # allow retrieval through H[key] method
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    # allow assignment through H[key] method
    def __setitem__(self, key, data):
        self.put(key, data)

    # print method
    def __str__(self):
        s=''
        for k in self.slots:
            if k != None:
                s = s + str(k) + ': ' + str(self.get(k)) + '\n'
        return s[:-1] # remove final newline character
```

Comment: Your indentation is messed up.

Comment: Just pretend its all indented once more. The copy-paste ignores the first tab for some reason.

Comment: Ok, it's fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some very quick notes.

1. The algorithm in `remove` is incorrect — it can leave keys unfindable.

   This is a common mistake! In *The Art of Computer Programming*, Knuth comments, "Many computer programmers have great faith in algorithms, and they are surprised to find that the obvious way to delete records from a hash table doesn't work." (Vol. III, p. 533.)

   If you want to get this right, Knuth gives an algorithm (pp. 533–4) for deletion in a open hash table with linear probing.

   But a simpler approach is to replace the deleted key with a special key meaning "there was a key here but it was deleted" which you later remove when growing or shrinking the table.

   **Update:** To create a unique key that you can be sure won't collide with any key passed by the user, just call [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object):

   ```
   _DELETED = object()  # slot had a key but it was deleted
   ```
2. The use of `copy.deepcopy` in the `grow` and `shrink` methods is wrong — this will make deep copies of the keys and values in the hash table, which isn't what you want (the caller will expect to be able to retrieve the actual item they stored in the table, not some copy of it) and might invalidate the hashes of the keys. You need a shallow copy instead.
3. It looks as though I can't use `None` as a key. This seems unsatisfactory.

   **Update:** You asked for use cases. Well, consider using a hash table to memoize a function that might take `None` as an argument (like [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)). Or using a hash table to count the number of occurrences of each element of an iterable (like [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)). Also it's nice to be able to document that any hashable object can be used as a key, without having to mention any special cases.

   It's quite straightforward to implement. Wherever the code has `None` to mean an empty slot, use some other unique object instead:

   ```
   _EMPTY = object()    # slot is empty
   ```
4. The `rehash` method is always called with `len(self.slots)` as the second argument, so there's no need for that argument — the method can just as well compute the size.
5. The `get` and `put` methods are redundant: you could just use `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.
6. The `grow` and `shrink` methods are almost identical. This common code could be shared.
7. `del newHashTable` is unnecessary — when the method returns, the last reference to `newHashTable` disappears and it will be collected in any case.
8. There's lots of duplicated code between the `__init__` and `clearTable` methods — why not have `__init__` call `clearTable`?

Comment: If I could I'd give you +10 for the `remove`. I completely missed that.

Comment: Hi Gareth, thank you very much for these points! 4 ,7, and 8 were straightforward, and I think those types of tips will totally help me in the future as general guidelines. For 2, I was confused about what a user would actually want to access, but yeah, a shallow copy makes more sense. For 6, I wrote a `resize` method that takes a `newSize` argument: thanks! For 3, would you mind giving an example of when you'd use `None`? For 5, it seems like a style choice to me, but I've noticed a lot of people define methods first, then at the end of the class they define the `__method__` to call it.

Comment: So that's how I'd justify my choices for 5. As for the big 1... amazing catch. I can see the problem very clearly now. Do you have a suggestion for the special key value? If it was a string like `'REMOVED'` then would I just have to specify in the documentation that that value is reserved, and then put something in the `hash()` method to prevent the user from using it? Thanks again for that catch!

Comment: @swagrov: See updated answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble deciding on how to implement the `_EMPTY` object. At first I put it inside the `__init__`, but because my `resize` function initializes a new HashTable, it seems to be changing the address of the `_EMPTY` object, so my equality checks (`== self._EMPTY`) are failing after the table is resized. I replaced `copy.deepcopy` with `copy.copy`, but should I be doing something else? Or would you recommend I define `_EMPTY` outside of `__init__` so it's like a static class variable?

Comment: @swagrov: If you allocate it in `__init__`, each instance of the class will create a different object. I would make it a global.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried and it seems to be working (same for my `_DELETED` object). I'm glad my attempt matches your suggestion. This has all been very illuminating for me!